# jquery ui datepicker - need a draggable date version

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, draggable

The jquery UI datepicker functionality is great, but I'd like to replicate the google analytics style date picker where you can select a range of dates by dragging from start to end.  I don't think the datepicker can do this, nor the excellent filamentgroup range picker.

Anyone done this before and have either some mods to jquery ui datepicker or some other reference for me to consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching for a jQuery plugin that supports selecting a range of dates.

Amazingly, the only one I found is for Prototype:

http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe

The author's words sums up my problem with other existing "solutions":

> I’m just sick of multiple date pickers on the same page.

If anyone knows of a jQuery plugin, please post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [fullcalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), it has a lot of the functionality you're interested in, including some great-looking drag and drop support.

Comment: Looks great for calendar style UIs, but the demo isn't really a datepicker for forms.  Looking for a form interface element for picking dates where you can drag to select the date range

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread your post as looking for Google Calendar-like interfaces.  I'll leave the post up in case someone else stumbles on this and could use the link.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old and that this solution isn't JQuery-UI specific but if someone comes looking for quick search then suggest taking a look at [Date Range Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daterangepicker)